# Good UX for container alignment for main content

Tags: interface-design, page-layout, critique, user-experience

I'm working on User Interface and I'm trying to figure out if a left alignment on the body container or a center alignment would work/look better. I'm adding screenshots of my project.

Have there been any testing done in relation to this or is there a recommended structure on the layout that gives users the better experience?

[image: View-A]

[image: View-B]

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't go for none of the above.

I find it very annoying to have everything aligned to the left of the screen.

I would add a wrap container and center that to the screen. Add a darker BG color to your body to focus the attention to the center and there you have it.

[image]

> This appears to be a CMS-like interface so it will be used by the "admins"
>   quite frequently to update their website/profile so it would be even more
>   annoying to have to go all the way to the far left side of the screen
>   all the time to change between pages.

You want to be able to keep everything an eye-movement away and keep a nice posture when using it.

- Your first example forces you to keep your head twisted to the left and stress will build up in your neck leading to discomfort.
- Your second example forces you to turn your head front-left-front every time you want to change tabs and that may get highly irritable and will prove to be unproductive.

Try to keep things together (without overcrowding).

Comment: Very much agreed.... either center *all* containers as a collective, or make non-navigational containers have fluid widths.